# sec.axis() with a different transformation for each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a plot faceted by region where the y-axis is the number of cases in the region and the 2nd y-axis is the number of cases per 100k population.

Since each region has a different population the transformation would be different for each region.

Can I do that with sec.axis() ?

Basically this, but I want to add a secondary y-axis that shows the number of cases per 100k given that Ontario's population is 12M and Quebec's population is 8M (so divide cases by population then multiply by 100k)

```
cases <- tibble::tribble(
  ~province, ~date_report, ~avg_cases_last7,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-26",              111,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-26", 89.8571428571429,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-27", 116.857142857143,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-27", 93.4285714285714,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-28", 113.142857142857,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-28", 89.8571428571429,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-29", 118.285714285714,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-29", 90.4285714285714,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-30", 117.714285714286,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-30",               97,
  "Ontario", "2020-08-31", 117.571428571429,
  "Quebec", "2020-08-31", 107.285714285714,
  "Ontario", "2020-09-01", 124.571428571429,
  "Quebec", "2020-09-01", 115.857142857143,
  "Ontario", "2020-09-02", 126.714285714286,
  "Quebec", "2020-09-02", 114.428571428571,
  "Ontario", "2020-09-03", 128.428571428571,
  "Quebec", "2020-09-03", 125.285714285714,
  "Ontario", "2020-09-04", 130.142857142857,
  "Quebec", "2020-09-04", 141.857142857143,
  "Ontario", "2020-09-05", 136.285714285714,
  "Quebec", "2020-09-05", 151.428571428571
) %>%
  mutate(date_report = as.Date(date_report))

ggplot(cases, aes(x= date_report, y = avg_cases_last7)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~province,  scales = "free")
```

Comment: can you share some of your data?

Comment: added quick example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure wether there is an approach to make this work using simple facetting. Instead I would go for using `patchwork`:

1. Split your data by `province`
2. Make a plot for each province
3. Glue the plots together using `patchwork`

My approach below uses a helper function for plotting and makes use of `purrr::pmap` to loop over the provinces. The helper function takes three arguments, 1. the data for the province, 2. the province population and 3. to mimic the behaviour of facet warp a logical to indicate wether the y-axis should be labelled.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

cases_split <- cases %>% 
  split(.$province)

make_plot <- function(d, pop, axis_label) {
  labs <- if (!axis_label) labs(y = NULL)
  name <- if (!axis_label) "cases per 100k"
  
  ggplot(d, aes(x = date_report, y = avg_cases_last7)) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / pop * 1e6, name = name)) +
    facet_wrap(~province,  scales = "free") +
    labs
}

purrr::pmap(list(d = cases_split, pop = list(12 * 1e6, 8 * 1e6), axis_label = c(TRUE, FALSE)), make_plot) %>% 
  patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
cases <- tibble::tribble(
      ~province, ~date_report, ~avg_cases_last7,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-26",              111,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-26", 89.8571428571429,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-27", 116.857142857143,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-27", 93.4285714285714,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-28", 113.142857142857,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-28", 89.8571428571429,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-29", 118.285714285714,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-29", 90.4285714285714,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-30", 117.714285714286,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-30",               97,
      "Ontario", "2020-08-31", 117.571428571429,
      "Quebec", "2020-08-31", 107.285714285714,
      "Ontario", "2020-09-01", 124.571428571429,
      "Quebec", "2020-09-01", 115.857142857143,
      "Ontario", "2020-09-02", 126.714285714286,
      "Quebec", "2020-09-02", 114.428571428571,
      "Ontario", "2020-09-03", 128.428571428571,
      "Quebec", "2020-09-03", 125.285714285714,
      "Ontario", "2020-09-04", 130.142857142857,
      "Quebec", "2020-09-04", 141.857142857143,
      "Ontario", "2020-09-05", 136.285714285714,
      "Quebec", "2020-09-05", 151.428571428571
    ) %>%
      mutate(date_report = as.Date(date_report))
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a solution that creates 2 plots and arranges them using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1= ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = cases[cases$province == 'Ontario', ], aes(x= date_report, y = avg_cases_last7)) +
  facet_wrap(~province,  scales = "free")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
    trans =  ~ . / 12000000*100000))+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0))

p2= ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = cases[cases$province == 'Quebec', ], aes(x= date_report, y = avg_cases_last7)) +
  facet_wrap(~province)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
    trans =  ~ . / 8000000*100000))+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 5))

p = grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2,
             left = 'avg_cases_last7', right = 'Number of cases per 100k ?', bottom = 'date_report')

ggsave(p, filename = 'plot.png', device = 'png', width = 6.75, height = 3)
```

Comment: thanks for answering!  I received 2 good answers almost simultaneously.  I'm not sure of the etiquette, guess I'll accept the 1st one?

Comment: @Zoltan, I agree with you! and I think the accepted answer seems more generic!